# How to I remove some of the extra lines under code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is what my code Looks like:

[image: This is what my code looks like]

I would like to remove these lines:

[image: I would like to remove these lines]

Answer (score 0):

These are the indentation guides. You cannot hide *some* of them.

To hide all of them, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the `Preferences: Open JSON Settings` command. Add the following line:

```json
"editor.guides.indentation": false
```

See [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) for reference.

Comment: you can also change this in the Settings GUI, search for `indentation`